# when i add an image to my app, the AVD won't load and i get this message

Tags: android

'qemu: could not open disk image C:\Users\William.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd\sdcard.img: Operation not permitted
Error accepting connection, aborting'

how do i fix it? bear in mind i'm an ultimate beginner

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same problem. I solved it by going to the AVD Manager and removing the virtual device and then add a new virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Using **Android studio** IDE and I always face to such problems. For dealing with this matter, one approach is to :

1. **Tools** > **AVD Manager** > **Run your Virtual Device**
2. Run your program while your Virtual Device is completely loaded.

This solution works for me. Hopefully it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to run two emulators at the same time and both use the same sdcard image file (sdcard.img).

Most likely you have duplicated an AVD definition that used this sdcard file and the original AVD instance was already running when you launched the clone.

The solution is to **edit the newly created AVD definition**, go to "Show advanced settings" -> "Memory and storage" -> "SDCard" and point to another image file or select "Studio managed".